# Accordion element opens by default when loaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-accordion

I have accordion implemented as a FAQ list with data consumed from ASP.NET WebApi. When the page loads, the accordion displays the data with the panel-body opened by default. This isn't the default behavior from where I copied it. I checked that the data-parent attribute was added to make sure all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one collapsible item is shown.

Below is the code for my accordion. Please note...I'm using angularjs as front-end to consume the api

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <div dir-paginate="emp in Emps | filter:search | orderBy:key:AscOrDesc | itemsPerPage:5" class="wrapper center-block">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{emp.Id}}">
                    <div role="button"
                         data-toggle="collapse"
                         data-parent="#accordion"
                         href="#collapse{{emp.Id}}"
                         aria-expanded="true"
                         aria-controls="collapse{{emp.Id}}"
                         ng-click="GetFamilyByFuId(emp.Id);">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            {{emp.FamilyUnitName}}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse{{emp.Id}}" 
                     class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                     role="tabpanel" 
                     aria-labelledby="heading{{emp.Id}}">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div ng-repeat="f in Fam" class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-1">{{f.Id}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">{{f.FirstName}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">{{f.Surname}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">{{f.RiskAreaId}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">{{f.RoleId}}</div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">{{f.LocationId}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the associated css file referenced on the page.

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
}
@media(max-width:992px){
 .wrapper{
  width:100%;
} 
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
    border:0;
}
.panel-title>a, .panel-title>a:active{
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
  color:#555;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
  word-spacing:3px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.panel-heading  a:before {
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   content: "\e114";
   float: right;
   transition: all 0.5s;
}
.panel-heading.active a:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

And this is the js file referenced on the page:

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
});

$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.panel-heading').addClass('active');
});
```

Please note that I'm using JQuery version 1.9.1 and bootstrap 3 in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The accordion in version 1.9 is open the first element by default. To be able to close all of them you need to add this

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
});
```

With this you will be able to close all the sections all the time.

Tell me if with this is fix...if not, I will try to help you!

Comment: This did not work as it didn't fix it. The .Selector is .panel-collapse